# Engaged handbrake & reversing

Tags: manual-transmission

This morning I got into the car, applied the clutch, selected reverse, and heard a crunch sound.  Now when I'm driving and I go to stop or slow down I hear this metal-on-metal grinding noise.
Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: Have the brakes checked - one or more pads may have been destroyed leaving metal to metal contact.

Comment: Agree with @SolarMike.  Sounds like the friction material may have come off the brake pad.  You will need to get them checked and possibly replaced.

Comment: Sometimes it is a small stone trapped between the caliper and the brake disk. It makes a grinding noise out of proportion to the cause, as if there is something seriously wrong with the transmission or engine. It usually stops when I am braking. Sometimes it will bounce out on its own, at other times the caliper has to be loosened to free it.